# ld: library not found for -lDoubleConversion React Native 0.62.2 when "Archive" in Xcode but I can build and run my app with Xcode

Tags: xcode, react-native-ios

When I do archive build, I got the following error. This has been discussed on stackOverflow before. But most of them are the case that the error happens at debug/build level. I don't have problems with build/run. Also, I tried everything I possibly can but none of them helps.

Here is how I get this error:

```
1) rm -rf node_modules
   npm install
   cd ios 
   pod install

2) open MyAppName.xcworkspace with Xcode.


3) Product -> Archive.
```

some more info about my setup:

in my Podfile, DoubleConversion lib is there.

```
pod 'DoubleConversion', :podspec => "#{rnPrefix}/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec"
```

from Xcode, this lib DoubleConversion is also linked

[image]

Does anyone can give me some suggestion?

Comment: I am also getting same error.
Did you find the solution?